# Attach a modal div to a dynamic set item using useRef

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native, use-ref

So i got this item objects from states after mapping through it, now what I want to do is whenever I hover to that item, I want a modal to show close to it, if im correct I can use Useref here to target the item location, here is how Ive done it

si first is map through the item array and the item div looks like this

```
  <div  key={item._id}  onMouseEnter={() => {itemhovered(i)}}  onMouseLeave={() => {itemunhovered()}} >
   <p>itemdetails</p>
  </div>
```

the i paramter is the location of that item from the array inside a state

now i pass it here

```
const [itemModal, setitemModal] = useState({ open: false, selecteditem: null });

  const itemhovered = (i) =>{
    console.log(i)

    setitemModal({open: true,selecteditem: recentlyAdded[i]})  
    console.log(recentlyAdded[i])   ///recentlyAdded is a state array
   
  }
  const itemunhovered = ()=>{
    console.log('unhovered')
  }

  const hoveritemModal = ()=>{
    return (
    
    <p className={ (itemModal.open? 'flex':'hidden' ) }> {itemModal.selecteditem.title} the item title </p>)
  }
```

im already getting correct result from the items that i hover now i want to attach the hoveritemModal to that item which will render a

beside it

so that the item div will look like this

```
<div  key={item._id}  onMouseEnter={() => {itemhovered(i)}}  onMouseLeave={() => {itemunhovered()}} >
   <p>itemdetails</p>

   <p> the item title </p>
  
</div>
```

how can i do this using useRef hook?

Comment: What you're describing is more of a tooltip/popover rather than a modal.

Comment: I want to some information of that item, when user hovered on that item, if a popover of tooltip can do that it think thats fine also @JoelHager